df difference in output of -H and -h
When I do a df -H ., the free space is displayed as, i.e., 7.1G. If I do a df -h ., it shows as 6.6Gi. I think the difference in the numbers stems from the fact is that the latter assumes 1 GB as being 1000000000 bytes, while the former takes 1 GB = 102410241024 bytes. What is the meaning of the letter i? Perhaps related somehow to the inodes? I find the man page not very clear on this.
BTW, running GNU df would show in the two cases the same figures, but without the i.

"Gi" or "GiB" is an abbreviation of "Gibibyte," 2^30 bytes. There are similar definitions for "Kibibyte," "Mebibyte," and so on, all based on powers of 2^10 rather than 10^3.
Prefixes for binary multiples (nist.gov)

Probably worth adding that, traditionally, some computer terms (mainly for bits/bytes, though usually excepting disk storage) have misused the standard K/M/G/etc. SI prefixes to mean powers of 1024 (= 2¹⁰) instead of 1000.  More recently, the newer Ki/Mi/Gi/etc. prefixes have been added to SI to take over that function and remove the ambiguity.  If everyone switched over to them, life would be much simpler — but it's taking some time…
